# Inside if condition, toggle a var to true, false, true, false

Tags: php

I really don't understand what is happening. When you click on a submit button with the name "submitTriageRecherchePrix", the variable $triagePrixDESC will be true. But when you click it again, it looks like the variable $triagePrixDESC will reset, and then it will shows up true again. What I want is to be able to click a submit button once, then my var is defined as true, then if you click it again, it will be false, etc. How can I do that?

```
if(Input::exists('submitTriageRecherchePrix')) {
    if($triagePrixDESC) {
        $triagePrixDESC = false;
    } else {
        $triagePrixDESC = true;
    }

    var_dump($triagePrixDESC);
}
```

Comment: Every time a script runs, the variables will indeed be reset. Take a look at *sessions* to have variables persist across HTTP requests. (`session_start()` at the top of your PHP and `$_SESSION['triagePrixDESC']` as your variable...)

Comment: thank you!! I really don't know why I didn't realise that..

Answer (score 1):

To maintain state you would need to use sessions:

```
session_start();

if(Input::exists('submitTriageRecherchePrix')) {
    if($_SESSION['triagePrixDESC']) {
        $_SESSION['triagePrixDESC'] = false;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['triagePrixDESC'] = true;
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION['triagePrixDESC']);
}
```

There may be some `Session` class in whatever framework/library you're using.

I was curious so I looked.  You may be using `FuelPHP` so: http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/session/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submitTriageRecherchePrix'])){
     $triagePrixDESC = false;
    } else {
        $triagePrixDESC = true;
    }
var_dump($triagePrixDESC);
}
```